# Checking anyobject value in Swift

Tags: swift

With the following piece of code:

```
let decoded = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data as! NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:  nil) as! [String:AnyObject]
```

I get `[latitude: 40.3654922, won: 1, longitude: 49.9384457, winnerID: 552e]`.

And now I want to check if won object equal to '1' do something. But I cannot check the value of the object. I s any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if let won = decoded["won"] as? Int {
    if won == 1 {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With swift 1.2, you can do:

```
if let won = decoded["won"] as? Int where won == 1 {
    // do something
}
```

Take a look at swift 1.2 release note (included in Xcode 6.3 release notes), we find that `if let` now support multiple condition check. For example:

```
if let a = foo(), b = bar() where a < b,
   let c = baz() {
}
```

or

```
if someValue > 42 && someOtherThing < 19, let a = getOptionalThing() where a > someValue {
}
```

Very powerful!